# Custom Qt QGraphicsItem tooltip

Tags: c++, qt

I'm looking for some ways to implement a simple custom tooltip for `QGraphicsItem`.

I know that I can use `setToolTip` to set text for tooltip. Now what I want is to change the text dynamically when the mouse hovers at different parts of a `QGraphicsItem` object.

What I'm thinking to do is when I get an event `QEvent::ToolTip`, I change the tooltip text in that event handler. However, I cannot find an event function that recieve `QEvent::ToolTip` for `QGraphicsItem`.

Or is there some ways to handle an event that mouse hovers for 2 seconds.

How can I make it?

Comment: Did you try [`QGraphicsItem::sceneEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#sceneEvent) or [`QGraphicsItem::sceneEventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#sceneEventFilter)? It might not work though, as you might end up in a loop where you constantly change the tooltip text. A better solution might be to use child `QGraphicsItem`s.

Comment: I have implemented a new class that Inherits `QGraphicsItem`.  And `QGraphicsItem::sceneEvent` does not recieve `QEvent::ToolTip`, which occurs when a tooltip is requested. I think a subsitution for `QEvent::ToolTip` is an event that mouse hovers and stays for 2 or 3 seconds. But I have no idea about how to make it.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement the [`hoverMoveEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#hoverMoveEvent) in your derived `QGraphicsItem` class, and [set the tooltip](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setToolTip)  based on the position within the graphics item

```
void MyItem::hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent* event)
{
    QPointF p = event->pos(); 
    // use p.x() and p.y() to set the tooltip accrdingly, for example:
    if (p.y() < height()/2)
        setTooltip("Upper Half");
    else
        setTooltip("Bottom Half");
}
```

Notice that you have to [enable hover events](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setAcceptHoverEvents) for your item.

Comment: A tooltip need to show when the mouse hovers and stays for a few seconds but not at the moment the mouse hovers. That's what `QEvent::ToolTip` do.